# is ARCGIS 10 very slow?

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-server

has anyone having problem with latest release of arcgis 10?

my services running on ags 10 is very slower than 9.3.1.

And Arcgis Desktop is Really slow which cause me to downgrade back to 9.3.1.

Is it just me or anyone else having issues like this?

Comment: This probably belongs on superuser

Answer (score 3):

This "upgrade" from 9.3.1 to 10 is not worth it.  I have a very new machine with fast processors and video cards and 10 runs much much slower.  Just creating a simple buffer takes around 2 minutes where in 9.3.1 it would finish in about 10seconds.  Unacceptable...

Answer (score 2):

We just switched over to Arc 10 a couple of days before service pack 1 came out.  We had some serious issues including speed problems with ArcGIS Server, Image Server and IMS.  We applied the service pack and it took care of most of our issues on the servers.

We have not applied SP1 to the desktops or ArcSDE since we are limited by 3rd party tools that need to be tested first.  But I am hoping that the problems we still see on the desktops hitting SDE will be resolved once we can apply SP1 there as well.

Comment: thanks lemur, i will try sp1. as we gave up upgrading to 10 because there is not huge difference in .net api

Answer (score 1):

I have had `arc 10` since September. Its been the worst experience of my professional career. Besides the crashes or lock ups 3 to 4 times per day, sometimes much more, it is the slowest program I have ever had the displeasure of dealing with. I have a brand new machine with up to date video card and 16 GB of memory and it still takes longer to do the simplest tasks that I don't see how they can stay in business if this is the norm. HORRIBLE HORRIBLE Exp. I would not recommend this to anyone. If there is another option besides `arc` I would definitely go with that.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't had any problems with Arcgis 10. However please note that the system requirements for ArcGIS 10 are much higher than ArcGIS 9.3.1

What are your hardware & software specifications? Do they meet the minimum requirements?